# Azure BotFramework Directline polling interval causes events to continuously trigger

Tags: node.js, azure, events, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am currently developing a prototype to communicate data between a chatbot and website elements. I am using the Azure Bot Services BotFrameworkAdapter and DirectLine in order to communicate between the two applications.

I am having a problem which I have narrowed down to the 'pollingInterval' property of the DirectLine object. The documentation says:

```
Clients that poll using HTTP GET should choose a polling interval that matches their intended use.

Service-to-service applications often use a polling interval of 5s or 10s.

Client-facing applications often use a polling interval of 1s, and issue a single additional request shortly after every message that the client sends (to rapidly retrieve a bot's response). This delay can be as short at 300ms but should be tuned based on the bot's speed and transit time. Polling should not be more frequent than once per second for any extended period of time.
```

To my understanding this is how the DirectLine object receives events from the bot, however I only need the event to trigger once, and not on the polling interval. It seems like there is no way to say "I am finished with this event" and move on. As soon as it is triggered once, it is continuously triggered which is causing issues with the functionality of the application.

I have this BotConnection object that is used to create a DirectLine instance and subscribe event handlers to the received events:

```
import { DirectLine } from 'botframework-directlinejs';
export default class BotConnection {
    constructor() {
        //Connect to directline object hosted by the bot
        this.connection = new DirectLine({
            domain: 'http://localhost:3001/directline',
            pollingInterval: 1000,
            webSocket: false
        })
    }
    getConnection() {
        return this.connection;
    }
    subscribeEventHandler(name, handle) {
        console.log('subscribeEventHandler');
        this.connection.activity$
        .filter(activity => activity.type === "event" && activity.name === name)
        .subscribe(activity => handle(activity));
    }
}
```

I am implementing the botConnection class in my App file like so:

```
props.botConnection.subscribeEventHandler('changePage', () => console.log('test'));
```

My Bot file takes a message and sends an event to the page that should be handled once on the client application:

```
const { ActivityHandler } = require('botbuilder');

class MyBot extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
            //Testing directline back-channel functionality
            if(context.activity.text === "Change page") {
                await context.sendActivity({type: 'event', name: 'changePage', value: '/test'});
            }
        await next();
     }
}

Any help with this issue would be fantastic. I am unsure if there is something supported by Azure or if there is some custom magic that I need to do.

Thanks
```

Comment: Does the issue persist if you set webSockets to true and get rid of the polling interval?

Comment: I would need to use WebSockets rather than HTTP requests so I would have to rewrite some logic. It's not the end of the world but I would prefer a built-in solution. Maybe this is just how the library works? I have implemented a custom solution for now but am interested if there is anything supported by Azure

Comment: I believe it should only be triggered once. Are you trying to build a Web Chat React client?

Comment: If you want to create a React Bot Framework Client and you're not interested in using [Web Chat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), I would recommend looking at the [Custom UI Web Chat Sample](). It uses the BotFramework-WebChat-Core dependency, which wraps BotFramework-DirectLineJs in Redux,  to build a custom UI. I'll look in to your Direct Line issue a bit more to see if i can figure it out in the meantime.